# Are there any races that follow the God Nerull in D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, races, religions-and-deities, greyhawk

I have found many a wiki that talk about the god Nerull from Greyhawk in D&D, and they all talk about how his followers are necromancers and murderers. I feel like I'm missing something though in finding information on his followers: is there a race that follows him?

The Orcs follow Gruumsh and the Elves follow Seldarine. It seems like there's got to be an equivalent for Nerull. So are there any races that follow Nerull or is it just the necromancers and murderers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ghouls

According to *Dungeon Magazine* #70, *Kingdom of the Ghouls*, p. 71:

> The god of the ghouls is unknown to outsiders; often called the Lord of Rot and Shadow, or simply the Lord of All Ghouls, many scholars believe the creature is an Abyssal Lord, though others believe it is some form of greater yugoloth or demi-god. In fact, the power answering ghoul prayers is none other than **Nerull, the Reaper. Ghouls are the only race whose worship he enjoys**; more sensible races worship Nerull merely to placate him.

However, according to later sources, the god of the ghouls is the demigod Doresain. In Dragon #70, Doresain is merely a powerful ghoul.

There are also some humans who worship Nerull, particular the Flan people (of the World of Greyhawk setting), although such worship is not ubiquitous among humans of that world. The sense I get is that a lot of people will make some offerings to Nerull to appease him, but few take him as their primary patron.